# SSH key not found when using system() to send git commands to command prompt in windows

Tags: r, windows, git, ssh

I am trying to execute git commands with a public SSH key using the `system()` function in R (on Windows 7 64 bit).  When I try to execute a git command I get the following error:

```
ssh_askpass: exec(rpostback-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can run the exact same command on the command prompt and it works.  I can also run the exact same command on the git bash shell and it works.  I am not sure why `cmd` can't find the key when run from R using the `system()` command.  Is there a way to specify the key location for the command prompt used by the `system()` command?

Update:
An example call that won't work:

```
system("git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.mygit.com:MyGroup/testGitlab.git master")
```

also

```
system("git clone git@gitlab.mygit.com:MyGroup/gitLabTest.git")
```

Both of these calls get the same error above.

**Update 2:** It appears that the ssh keys are not visible from R using `list.files()`

```
> list.files("C:/Users/Me/Documents/.ssh/", all.files = TRUE)
[1] "."  ".."
```

I have verified that there are multiple ssh keys in this directory which are visible from the git bash shell using `ls -a`.

Comment: What exactly does your call to `system()` look like?

Comment: Is your private key passphrase-protected?

Comment: No,there is no password for the key. Again, the exact same command works on the command prompt without any additional input.

Comment: just double-checking: your shell startup options (`.bashrc` etc.) don't use something like `ssh-add` to add key info to a keychain?  does `env | grep SSH` get you anywhere?

Comment: @BenBolker I am not sure I understand your question?  If I open git bash (which is where I generated the keys) I can view the key files and everything works as expected.  In windows command prompt I can push and pull from gitLab without issues but when I `ls -a` in the .ssh directory I just get the `.` and `..`, no key files are visible.  Finally, when I try to run the same commands through `system()` from an R session I get the above ssh error.  Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it turns out, on my Windows system (7, 64 bit), when creating SSH keys with the git bash shell they were saved to "C:\Users\MyAcount\.ssh".  However, the `cmd.exe`  called by `system()` in `R` was looking in "C:\Users\MyAccount\Documents\.ssh".

For some reason, when using the `cmd` prompt called directly from the OS it looks in the same .ssh directory as the bash shell.  Go Figure.  Windows, I don't think I will ever understand you.  Hope this helps someone out there.